# Does Spark 3.0.1 support custom Aggregators on window functions?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark3

I wrote a custom `Aggregator` (an extension of `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator`) and Spark invokes it correctly as an aggregating function under `group by` statement:

```
sparkSession
    .createDataFrame(...)
    .groupBy(col("id"))
    .agg(
        new MyCustomAggregator().toColumn().name("aggregation_result"))
    .show();
```

I would like to use it within window function though, because ordering matters to me.
I've tried invoking it like that:

```
sparkSession
    .createDataFrame(...)
    .withColumn("aggregation_result", new MyCustomAggregator().toColumn().over(Window
        .partitionBy(col("id"))
        .orderBy(col("order"))))
    .show();
```

That's the error I get:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(PARTITION BY `id` ORDER BY `order` ASC NULLS FIRST unspecifiedframe$())' due to data type mismatch: Cannot use an UnspecifiedFrame. This should have been converted during analysis. Please file a bug report.
```

Is it at all possible to use custom Aggregators as window functions in Spark 3.0.1?
If so, what am I missing here?

Comment: Seems like you need to use UDAF instead of Aggregator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261663/spark-cannot-use-an-unspecifiedframe-this-should-have-been-converted-during-a

Comment: @mck this question was asked two years ago, when Spark 3.0, which introduced significant changes to user defined aggregation, was not around.

Comment: yeah, but you seem to be getting the same error. can you use UDAF instead?

Comment: That would be OK as long as it works, however I was not so far able to make UDAF work either. A code snippet with an example would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udaf-scala.html

Comment: @mck this approach uses the deprecated UserDefinedAggregateFunction, which I would rather avoid

Comment: I believe you attempted to write a Custom Aggregator. UDAF's hard stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Spark 3 does indeed support custom aggregators as window functions.

Here is the Java code:

```
UserDefinedFunction myCustomAggregation = functions.udaf(new MyCustomAggregator(), Encoders.bean(AggregationInput.class));

sparkSession
    .createDataFrame(...)
    .withColumn("aggregation_result", myCustomAggregation.apply(col("aggregation_input1"), col("aggregation_input2")).over(Window
        .partitionBy(col("id"))
        .orderBy(col("order"))))
    .show();
```

`AggregationInput` here is a simple DTO with the row elements needed for your aggregation function.

So no matter whether you aggregate under `group by` or as a window function you still want to use `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator`.